# MS Access 2013 Type Conversion Failure when importing Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have been trying to import Excel spreadsheets into MS Access 2013 (Via the interface) as tables and producing "Type Conversion Failure" errors for a field "SegmentID" that is of Integer type.

> When checking the failed row numbers in the Excel spreadsheet they are indeed integers just as all the others.
>   Even re-entering and setting the entire column as numbers (and removing the decimal places) still produces the same error. I need to do this import for many spreadsheets and almost every one i try has the same error ranging from a handful to thousands randomly throughout the spreadsheet. The spreadsheets are of .xlsx format.

Any Idea's would be greatly appreciated. I have thought of manually doing this with something like:

`DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE TableName ([Date] DATETIME, [Name] TEXT, ETC..."`
`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "TableName", "C:\ExcelData.xlxs"`

Comment: Can you provide a sample .xlsx file that replicates the issue?

Comment: Here is the [Spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukd4rz9u44yz3s5/Wildlife.xlsx). For this particular sheet there are a few errors but the type is still the same. I may not be able to produce others as some could be data sensitive material. Here are the [Spreadsheet Import Errors](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gifnjx2edobr33d/Wildlife_ImportErrors.xlsx) as well.

Comment: I would suggest to convert the xls to csv and see what happens with a different file format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers range from -32,768 to +32,767 .  Your segment id looks like it needs a LONG integer.  Your spreadsheet appears to go to 33581 which puts you over integer range.

Comment: I agree. I just tested an import in Access 2010 and no errors occur if the [SegmentID] field in the Access table is defined as `Long Integer`.

Comment: Some of the import errors occur in rows where the SegmentID is 680. That and i checked the Imported Tables and the Data Type for the SegmentID and it was indeed a Long Integer. (Edit, i see your @GordThompson i will try again)

Comment: My mistake, i can't seem to recreate Errors where segments are in that range and using Long Integers fixes the import errors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned before i was going to try and manually create the table and import the data. All data is being transferred to the created table with no errors or loss of data. In your "Visual Basic" view in MS Access hit `Ctrl + G` and you can use this code.

> `DoCmd.RunSQL ("CREATE TABLE Wildlife (ID COUNTER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SegmentID INT, RouteID TEXT, Type TEXT, Subtype TEXT, Subtype2 TEXT);")
>   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Wildlife", "C:\PathToFile\Wildlife.xlsx",-1`

`ID COUNTER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` Adds an AutoNumber field ID that is the primary Key

The `-1` argument at the end of the second `Do.Cmd` tells Access that the first row in the field is the column names. [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)